# Ambiguos Grammar detection algorithm

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I tried to solve if a grammar is ambiguous or not.
I know that I have to find a word that can be generate by two different leftmost derivations.
Is there any algorithm to find a word that, if the grammar is ambiguous, can be generated by two different trees?
[This question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41586/ambiguous-context-free) is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous context free](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41586/ambiguous-context-free)

Comment: @rici, I'm not quite understanding how it is a duplicate; can you elaborate?

Comment: @D.w.: ok, how about this one: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84475/how-to-check-for-ambiguous-grammar-if-you-dont-know-the-string. I just gave a hard time believing that there isn't a duplicate somewhere on this site. (I was rushing this morning, sorry. But the answer to the Q I suggested does include "it is undecidable whether a given CF grammar is ambiguous (1962-63, Cantor - Floyd - Chomsky and Schutzenberger)", which is certainly the answer to this Q.

Comment: The algorithm is to enumerate all parse trees and to check whether there is a word generated twice. If your grammar is ambiguous then the algorithm is guaranteed to halt.

Comment: Cool.  It looks like this post asks two questions: (1) can we determine whether a grammar is ambiguous or not; (2) if we know that the grammar is ambiguous, how can we find a word that can be generated by two different trees?  The first is a dup of https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84475/ as rici says.  The second is answered by Yuval.  edoardott, can you [edit] your post to focus only on the second question, so that we can answer it rather than marking it as a duplicate of that other question?